# %%timeit magic command and variable set to global in function

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, timeit

Here is a MRE:

```py
%%timeit

variable = 0

def func():
    global variable
    variable += 1

func()

assert (variable == 1)
```

It works perfectly without the magic command `%%timeit`.

I'm not sure I understand why it doesn't work when I add the magic command. It seems that it's due to the fact that the variable `variable` got set to `global`.

I'm using `VSCode` and `Python 3.11.1`

EDIT after It_is_Chris comment suggesting it was just an `AssertionError`.
This doesn't work either:

```py
%%timeit

variable = 0

def func():
    global variable
    variable += 1

func()

print(f"Variable is {variable}")
```

Comment: It is working, your `assert` is raising an `AssertionError` when `variable != 1`. For example, change the last line to `assert variable == 1, f'variable is {variable}'`

Comment: It's still not working, I removed the assert and I changed it with the print statement (https://i.imgur.com/tt8obs3.png)

Comment: I cannot replicate that issue. Using `%%timeit` with a print statement is working for me in python 3.8

Comment: It might be `3.11.1` related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've sort of figured it out, but it's weird. The short answer is to add a `global variable` at the very beginning.

```
%%timeit -n 5 -r 5

global variable

variable = 0

def func():
    
    global variable
    variable += 1

func()


assert (variable == 1)
```

I'm not sure of the specifics, but I think `%%timeit` is limiting the scope of your initial `variable` declaration while the `global variable` inside your function has larger scope. You can see this in action by removing the first `global variable` and printing out your `variable` inside the func.

```
%%timeit -n 5 -r 5

# global variable

variable = 0

def func():
    
    global variable
    variable += 1
    # Running this multiple times without global variable
    # above will show that this variable is somehow different
    # in scope
    print(variable)

func()


assert (variable == 1)
```

Manually re-running this block will show that the `variable` inside function will continue to iterate without resetting.